# Flutter Inspector Toggle Select Widget mode not working.

Tags: widget, flutter

I have build a Flutter app solely made of Stateless Widgets.
I run my `main.dart` (no *debug* mode) when I toggle the "Toggle Select Widget mode" button, and the widgets tree displays correctly.

**Problem**: I am able to click ONE widget in my UI, but then

1. The Widget tree pane does not show the widget I have clicked. There is no change.
2. Afterwards, I am unable to click/select any other widget.

I have tried:

- toggling the Select Widget button off and back on
- rebooting `main.dart`

I use Android Studio 3.1.2. My emulator is an iPhone 6s virtual device (I have also tried on a Nexus Android device, in vain). 
Here is a [copy of my working screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fi9N0.jpg), should it be useful.

Do you have an idea what I did wrong? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be solved as of version 3.2 of Android Studio (Sep 17, 2018 built).

Answer (score 0):

*Reasons for not working: **Flutter inspector does not go to code when I click***

1. The file ends with a digit (Example: "**MySpace 1**") Flutter Inspector does not work.
2. The file includes a digit like this (Example: "**MySpace 1 - Planet**") Flutter Inspector does not work.

*How to fix*

If you change the file name manually, for example, delete 1("MySpace 1") and change it to ("**MySpace**"), it will  work.

Additionaly the file ends with like this ("**MySpace_1**") or ("**MySpace1**").It will work,too.